# Drawing line of regression onto scatter graph in python

Tags: python, statistics, regression

I am trying to draw the line of regression onto a scatter graph. I have two functions:

```
def place_y(x, slope, intercept):
    return slope * x + intercept


def draw_line_of_regression():
    """The line of regression can be used to predict further values"""
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # used to draw graph
    from scipy import stats

    # Example shows relationship between age and speed
    age_x = [5, 7, 8, 7, 2, 17, 2, 9, 4, 11, 12, 9, 6]
    speed_y = [99, 86, 87, 88, 111, 86, 103, 87, 94, 78, 77, 85, 86]

    slope, intercept, r, p, std_error = stats.linregress(age_x, speed_y)
    # gets variables used in drawing the line of regression

    line_of_regression = list(map(place_y(age_x, slope, intercept), age_x))

    plt.scatter(age_x, speed_y)  # draws scatter graph
    plt.plot(age_x, line_of_regression)
    plt.show()  # shows the graph


draw_line_of_regression()
```

When this is run there is an error with the place_y() function. Error:

```
    return slope * x + intercept
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` [expects a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as the first argument while you're giving it `place_y(age_x, slope, intercept)` as the first argument (which throws error during execution because there's no multiplication of list and float defined). You have to pass the function itself, but "freeze" all arguments except `x`. To do that you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```python
import functools

...
    line_of_regression = list(map(functools.partial(place_y, slope=slope, intercept=intercept), age_x))
    ...
```

However, a better way to do the same is to utilize list comprehension:

```python
...
    line_of_regression = [place_y(x, slope, intercept) for x in age_x]
    ...
```

Even better is to leverage numpy's vectorized operations

```python
...
    age_x = np.array([5, 7, 8, 7, 2, 17, 2, 9, 4, 11, 12, 9, 6])
    ...
    line_of_regression = age_x * slope + intercept
    ...
```